# SSD and Partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd

Recently Windows laptop has been upgraded; the laptop has 256 SSD.

Attached is the screenshot of storage.

Would like to create another partition disk (D drive). My question is should I create an SSD explicitly or it is hidden?

[image: Storage]

Update 1
[image: Storage]

Update 2

[image: Storage]

Comment: You don’t have a partition with a drive letter other then your system partition.  Your SSD does not appear in your screenshot.  It appears you have a single 1 TB drive attached to your system currently

Comment: @Ramhound How can I make sure whether the laptop has SSD? Any tool can identify SSD?

Comment: If your SSD was connected to your system it would appear as a disk within Disk Management.

Comment: @Ramhound Excuse for my ignorance, what must have happened during the re-installation of Windows in which the SSD has disappeared? Is there a way to retrieve it back?

Comment: Windows is installed (in the screenshot you provided) on a 1 TB drive.  There is a disk (unknown size) that isn’t being properly identified in your screenshot.

Comment: What is the SSD's manufacturer/model? What connection type (SATA, M.2 SATA, M.2 NVMe) does it use? Does it have a 'PSID' number written on it? Have you enabled BitLocker or OPAL disk encryption in the past? If I had to guess, "Disk 1" is a locked SSD (in OPAL PBE mode).

Comment: @Ramhound I have updated my question with another screenshot of storage.

Comment: @grawity It is Toshiba one, have updated my question with another screenshot of storage.

Comment: Most of that screenshot is about your 1TB HDD, not about the SSD, and it doesn't really answer any of the other questions.

Comment: @grawity The reason is I am not sure how to answer your question regarding SSD.

Comment: @grawity Included another screenshot from device manager, does this help?

Comment: Will repeat the fact all your screenshots indicate you don’t have a SSD installed in your system (or it’s locked as indicated previously)

Comment: Very enlightening: https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/628354-ssd-is-fcked-up/

Comment: Yes it seems that the device PS3109S9 is the bricked SSD. Google has a lot of hits for this.